# Java cannot find JavaFX modules

Tags: java, maven, javafx, module

I cloned my project from Gitlab and the project uses Maven. I also use JavaFX but only with Maven, I do not use external JARs.

When I build the project it shows errors indicating that it cannot find the modules.
See the screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THJFL.png)

My module-info.java

```
module com.example.fluganzeigetafel {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.desktop;


    requires com.google.zxing;
    requires pdfbox.app;

    opens com.example.fluganzeigetafel.Contract to javafx.base;
    opens com.example.fluganzeigetafel to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.fluganzeigetafel;
    exports com.example.fluganzeigetafel.Controller;
    opens com.example.fluganzeigetafel.Controller to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.fluganzeigetafel.Manager;
    opens com.example.fluganzeigetafel.Manager to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.fluganzeigetafel.Utility;
    opens com.example.fluganzeigetafel.Utility to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.fluganzeigetafel.CustomDialogs;
    opens com.example.fluganzeigetafel.CustomDialogs to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.fluganzeigetafel.Data;
    opens com.example.fluganzeigetafel.Data to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.fluganzeigetafel.Handler;
    opens com.example.fluganzeigetafel.Handler to javafx.fxml;
}
```

and a piece of pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19-ea+7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19-ea+7</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Does `mvn compile` give you the same error(s)?

Comment: I do not have Maven installed on my computer

Comment: If the project configured the Maven wrapper, then try `./mvnw compile`. Otherwise, install Maven. A project that uses Maven is meant to be built--and, in a development environment, executed--with Maven. You can have IntelliJ execute Maven goals (and IntelliJ may actually come with a version of Maven, not sure).

Comment: "_I also use JavaFX but only with Maven, I do not use external JARs._" -- This indicates that you should already have Maven installed. Not sure how you "only use Maven" without having Maven installed.

Comment: I use Maven in IntelliJ. Not an installed version

Comment: Is the error you're seeing coming from executing the `compile` phase? That screenshot doesn't look like Maven logs. Perhaps we need a [mre], including environment information.

Comment: The error comes when I click on Rebuild Project

Comment: I simply have a Project with GUI and added all configurations for JavaFX and Apache PDFBox but it cannot find the modules, but when I add the JARs it works but I want a Project that is not dependend on the user to download the JARs, instead Maven should handle this case.

Comment: Are the [Maven and Idea projects in sync](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#maven_reimport)? Also `ea` (early access) versions of software are for evaluation purposes, instead use a stable version of JavaFX, like 21.0.1.

Comment: My impression is that you're using IntelliJ's built-in build system instead of delegating to Maven (whether it's the Maven that comes with IntelliJ or not).

Comment: 1. Please execute the mvn goal "clean" in your IDE. There must be a menu called "Maven". If you do NOT see this menu, activate it. In this menu are all Maven goals listed. Double click on "clean". If this does not work, then your project is NOT a Maven project. This will be the issue.  If this works, then your project is a Maven project and it has an embedded Maven wrapper.

Comment: 2. If it works, please check from WHERE your Maven takes the dependencies. Only from your local Maven repo? Or is the central repo allowed too?

Comment: 3. IMO your version ids are very suspicious. Do they really exist?

Comment: 1. Don't use ea ("early access") versions unless you have a compelling reason. The current version of JavaFX at the time of writing is 21, so change both of the dependencies to use `<version>21</version>`. 2. Since you mentioned you're using IntelliJ, right click on the project (or on the `pom.xml`), choose "Maven" and "Reload project".

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: @James_D version `21` has [issues on startup with OS X Sonoma](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8315657), `21.0.1` or higher is recommended.  From the linked bug report: *"I can reproduce this on a macOS 14 beta system using the default settings. This is a fairly serious problem, since it means that every JavaFX application will experience a 5 second delay in startup followed by a warning message."*.